# Alterando caminho remoto no Git

Tags: git, git-remote

**PROBLEMA:**

Eu dei `git clone` no repositório do **[Web Starter Kit](https://github.com/google/web-starter-kit)** da Google e o projeto já vem com o Git iniciado e com `git remote origin master` configurado como padrão do Git.

Portanto, se eu executar o comando `git push origin master` o Git vai solicitar a permissão pra que eu possa upar as mudanças que fiz localmente pra conta da Google no GitHub, permissão esta que obviamente não tenho.

**PERGUNTA:**

Como posso alterar esse caminho remoto para que eu possa enviar os dados usando o comando `git push origin master`, de forma que envie para minha conta no Bitbucket, ao invés de enviar pra origem? (que no caso é a conta da Google no GitHub).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Você pode tanto remover

```
git remote remove origin
```

adicionar outra

```
git remote add origin git://suaUrl
```

quanto alterar

```
git remote set-url origin git://suaUrl
```